# Python Typing: Mypy errors with overload "overlap" when signatures are different

Tags: python, overloading, mypy, python-typing

The following code appears to generate two mypy errors: `Overloaded function signatures 1 and 3 overlap with incompatible return types` and `Overloaded function signatures 2 and 3 overlap with incompatible return types`; but all overloads have different signatures - Literal[True], Literal[False] and None do not overlap.

```py
@overload
def func_a(*, a: Literal[False] = ...) -> str:
    ...


@overload
def func_a(*, a: None = ...) -> str:
    ...


@overload
def func_a(*, a: Literal[True] = ...) -> int:
    ...


def func_a(*, a: Optional[bool] = None) -> str | int:
    if a:
        return 1
    return "foo"


var1 = func_a()  # str correctly discovered by VSCode Pylance
var2 = func_a(a=False)  # str correctly discovered by VSCode Pylance
var3 = func_a(a=True)  # int correctly discovered by VSCode Pylance
```

Why does Mypy think they overlap and how could I go about fixing this?

Mypy version: 0.991

Python version: 3.11.1

Comment: Isn't this happening because the overloads all have the same signature? Because they all have the same parameter name `a:`?

Comment: Does removing `= ...` from the signatures work?

Comment: @SeanCedric the signatures ARE different as the types are different. As per [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading) for overloads you're only supposed to change types.

Comment: `overload` only applies to *argument* types; you can't overload a function on its return type.

Comment: @chepner the example in the [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading) is exactly using overloads to overload the return type with different argument types.

Comment: @chepner: Python doesn't support return-type-*only* polymorphism (unlike, say, Haskell), but it is valid to annotate two overloads with different return types.

Comment: `overload` also apparently does not work properly with keyword-only arguments. *None* of your functions have any regular parameters, so the "signature" for all three is "void". Note that you only get an error for 1/3 and 2/3 (str vs int), not for 1/2 (where both functions return a `str`).

Comment: The return value doesn't take part in the overloading, though. Calls need to be distinguished by their arguments only.

Comment: @chepner: Keyword-only arguments don't affect anything important here. If you remove the `*,` parts, the same error messages still occur.

Comment: Yes, I see in your answer it's the lack of any required argument that causes the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that by writing `= ...` default values for every overload, you've marked the parameter as optional in *every overload*. A plain `func_a()` call matches every single overload of your function.

You need to resolve that, so `func_a()` only matches one overload. Here's one way:

```
@overload
def func_a(*, a: Literal[False]) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def func_a(*, a: Literal[True]) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def func_a(*, a: None = None) -> str:
    ...
```

Here, only the `None` overload marks the parameter as optional, so `func_a()` only matches that overload.

Alternatively, you could make the no-argument version its own overload:

```
@overload
def func_a(*, a: Literal[False]) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def func_a(*, a: Literal[True]) -> int:
    ...

@overload
def func_a(*, a: None) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def func_a() -> str:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly yet! Marking as accepted :)